# Difference between eclipse.ini and config.ini

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm building a RCP and trying to define an Eclipse system property; for example `eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval`. I understand that some properties can go into eclipse.ini under `-vmargs` with `-D` in the prefix. But I noticed that there are similar properties defined the same-ish way in config.ini.

Perhaps, programmatically it's easier to add to eclipse.ini when building?

What is the difference between those two ini files and which one is the convention for adding an Eclipse system property?

Comment: Depends. Follow how Eclipse and others do it. In contrast to the `config.ini`, you can have multiple `<product>.ini` files (see `--launcher.ini` argument). So IMHO I would put the things that are essential required and not intended to be changed into the `config.ini`. The `<product>.ini` will be read already by the executable. See also documentation: [_"Many of these properties have command line equivalents...."_](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).